# How to show pdf file in folder for download by codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, pdf

I uploaded different documents to a folder and when I want to have uploaded files stored in the folder to be displayed on all web pages, how to write and delete them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't have enough rep to comment. So, dropping an answer.

assuming you have not saved filenames in database.

you can make use of scandir()

[you can read the manual for scandir() function here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)

and to delete you can use unlink()

[You can read the manual for unlink() function here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)